# Rails create a user and a belongs_to model during sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want that when the user sign up (Devise) it create its first "Profile" account at the same time of registration form.

I tried with "fields_for" but it's not working. I can add an hidden_field in the registration form because the "user" is not created yet.
How can I do?

**Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable,  and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :trackable

class Profile < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user #creator
```

**Views (Sign up)**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :profiles, resource.profiles.build do |s| %>

        <%= s.text_field :name%>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles` on the model, and also permit `profiles_attributes` on the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a call back in the model.
Like `after_save` and then create a profile.

You can look up callbacks here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

And it could look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable,  and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :trackable

   after_save :create_profile

 def create_profile
    Profile.create(user: self,...)
  end
end
```

Another option would be to generate a devise controller yourself. You can follow the steps from their readme: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers

And as they suggest, tweak the create method, by adding
`Profile.new(...)`

```
def create
  super  #inherits from devise controllers and create the user model
  # now you can add your own code creating the Profile
  Profile.new(user: resource, ...)
end
```

Comment: Yes, but it this way I don't have access to the "name" attribute defined by user at sign up

Comment: Have you tried the above mentioned nested attributes?
You can also create a profile in the controller ... You have to create your own Devise Registrations Controller, which inherits from devise. I update the answer accordingly.